# How Port Scanner tells Hostnames on LAN?

Tags: networking, dns, port, scanner

The port scanner software I use is able to list IP addresses along with their hostnames on my LAN. **I am very puzzled how it gets the hostnames.** For example, I have a few Raspberry Pi's on the LAN, and the port scanner software is able to list all their hostnames.

I use `netstat -ant` on the Pi to find out that it is listening on no port other than port 22 (SSH), so I don't think it can respond to any other protocols.

I also try a variety of `nmap` commands, but none reveals the hostname:

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.0.*
sudo nmap 192.168.0.102
sudo nmap -R 192.168.0.102
```

Can anyone tell me how my port scanner software obtain the hostnames? Does it query the router?

Additional info: The port scanner software is called [Advanced Port Scanner](http://www.advanced-port-scanner.com)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the name of the software you are using.

Comment: If you can do a reverse DNS lookup for LAN names (because the router provides it) manually using `host` etc., the best guess is that your port scanner software, whatever it is, does the same, because it's the obvious method.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found an open source project called [Angry IP Scanner](https://github.com/angryip/ipscan), looked into the source code, and found the answer.

It basically queries the target machine's **UDP port 5353** (Multicast DNS) and **port 137** (NetBIOS) to find the hostname of that machine.

I missed those ports because `netstat -ant` only displays TCP ports. `netstat -anu` would have caught them.